# error LNK2019 and LNK1120 errors

Tags: linker-errors

I am trying to run a simple bit manipulation exercise to find the high bit position of an unsigned number in Visual Studio 2012 and I keep getting these errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _highBitPostion referenced
>   in function _main C:\Users\Dalton Pablo\Desktop\School\C539
>   projects\homework 4 C539\bitfiddling hw4.obj
>
> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\Dalton
>   Pablo\Desktop\School\C539 projects\homework 4 C539\Debug\homework 4
>   C539.exe  1

I have come across these errors in the past but always ended up running my program in the lab  becuase thier machines dont give me these problems. I have searched other similar problems on this site to solve the problem with little success.

I have already tried going into:

> properties > Configuration prop. > linker > system>

then changing subsystem to `Console`

I have updated my code to TooTones suggestion and unfortunately it didnt resolve the issue. Please let me know if you see anyway that my code causes these errors.

Here is my code for context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


unsigned highBitPosition (unsigned n);
unsigned long long highBitPosition64 (unsigned long long nn);

int main(void){
//unsigned n = 0x0BABE000U;

  printf("High Bit Postion 32: ");
  printf("%u", highBitPosition(0x0BABE000U));

}

unsigned highBitPosition (unsigned n){
unsigned pos;
  for ( pos = 31; pos > 0; pos--){

    if(((n >> pos) & 1U) == 1)

    return pos;
}

 return 0; }

unsigned long long highBitPosition64 (unsigned long long nn){

unsigned hiOrder, lowOrder, bitPos;

if (nn == 0) return 0;

hiOrder = nn >>32;
lowOrder = nn & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFULL;

    if( highBitPosition(hiOrder) != 0){
        bitPos = highBitPosition(hiOrder) + 32;
    }else
        bitPos = highBitPosition(lowOrder);

return bitPos;
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your revised code into vs2012 and it compiles and links fine for me. You could try doing a clean or rebuild (or starting from scratch with your new code as I did). You dont have `highBitPostion` in your code anymore, so I don't see how you can still have the error. PS if you comment on an answer someone has given, then they will get a notification; otherwise if you just update your question they might not know.

Comment: I have also tried that as well and it doesnt fix the problem. really is quite odd and frustrating. i think it has to do with some compiler setting somewhere, but i would really know where to begin.   im gonna see if my Prof. can help me take a look at it. thanks for the help. i will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

your forward **declaration**

```
unsigned highBitPostion (unsigned n);
```

doesn't match your **definition**

```
unsigned highBitPosition (unsigned n){
```

*Character for character* **the declaration needs to match the definition**. So you can't have a difference in lower/upper case, spelling mistakes, etc. Here you have a spelling mistake in the declaration.

So the linker is looking for a definition of `highBitPostion`, which it can't find, so it says that `highBitPostion` is missing. (It isn't smart enough to figure out that the function you *did* define, `highBitPosition`, is the one it should use!)